# VB.net 2 dimensional array with data from a list

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net, highcharts

Good evening,

I'm working since 8 hours on a simple ASP.net Chart Website (dotnet highcharts.com) and I'm having incredible trouble with the following:

I have to add a series to a chart with an 2 dimensional array of Object. So I can't use anything else.

This is how it looks right now, with hardcoded values:

```
  TokioData = New Object(,) {{1500, 3},{1700, 5}}
```

I only need to have the {value1, value2} part being added from a list / string or whatever.

But I can't get it to work ... I'm really not having any idea, as I'm googling the whole day, just to find out how to add KeyValuePairs to an 2D-Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that without array initializer syntax. First, initiate 2D array with minimum required size. Then use simple `For` loop to add each data from list to 2D array. For example :

```
'list where data stored initially
Dim list As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)) _
    From
    {
        New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(1500, 3),
        New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer)(1700, 5)
    }

Dim TokioData As Object(,)
'initate empty 2D array with size just enough to store all data from list
TokioData = New Object(list.Count - 1, 1) {}
'add data from list to 2D array
For i As Integer = 0 To list.Count-1
    TokioData(i, 0) = list(i).Key
    TokioData(i, 1) = list(i).Value
Next
```

Comment: You sir, are a freaking legend!!! Thank you sooo much there.
Exactly what I was looking for :)